# Calling listener in bean when pressing enter in JSF 2 h:inputText

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am currently writing my first JSF 2 page and I would like to implement the following:
When the user writes something in a h:inputText element and presses the enter button another h:inputText should get updated with some data out of a database.

My testpage contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Example</h3>

        <h:form>

           <h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{helloBean.name}">
              <f:ajax render="output" execute="inputField" event="keypress" listener="#{bean.myChangeListener}" /> 
           </h:inputText>
           <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.name}" /></h2>  

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The Bean contains all neccessary getters and setters and this function:

```
public void myChangeEvent( AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        System.out.println( "VALUE CHANGED" );

}
```

UPDATE 2013-12-16:

After hours of troubleshooting I found the problem why nothing was submitted when leaving the textfield or pressing enter in the textfield. My web application was created with templates and in the template for my page header was an 'a4j:status'  tag and this was in conflict with JSF 2. After removing the 'a4j:status'-line the myChangeEvent method gets called when I click somewhere else on the web page after editing the textfield value.

But there is stil the problem, that the whole page gets submitted when clicking on enter after changing the textfield value. This is because I have a button at the bottom of the page thats saves the user input and therefore submits the whole page, which is OK. But this button should not be called when pressing enter in the textfield. What do I have to add to my existing code?

**UPDATE 2013-12-17:**
After some trouble with JS I finally got it working with the help of L-Ray (thanks again).
Here I will show the final and working version with JQuery:

```
<h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{helloBean.name}" >
    <f:ajax render="output" execute="inputField" event="change"  listener="#{helloBean.myChangeEvent}" />
</h:inputText>
<h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.name}" /></h2>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#mainForm\\:inputField" ).bind('keypress', function(e) {

            var keyCcode = e.keyCode || e.which;

            // Enter was pressed
            if(keyCcode == 13) { 
                e.target.blur();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the omission of the `listener` attribute on `<f:ajax>` a typo?

Comment: Oh i am sorry this was a copy n paste error but still the listener (the myChangeListener method in the bean) does not get called

Comment: [Standard](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) says the change listener needs the signature `public void processAjaxBehavior(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException)`. Does adapting your listener to that fix the issue?

Comment: I tryed the AjaxBehaviorEvent and also tryed no parameter but the result is the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest not using the `listener="#{bean.myChangeEvent}"` attribute in the `inputText` (it expects the `ValueChangeEvent`), but a listener call from the `f:ajax`, which expects either no parameter or a `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

Also I would suggest not to listen to a keypressed-event inside the `f:ajax` but for a change-event, together with an javascript - keypress - event.

So as a solution, maybe the following code might work for you...

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{helloBean.name}" 
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {event.target.blur();event.stopPropagation();return false;} else {return true;};">
        <f:ajax render="output" execute="inputField" event="change" 
             listener="#{helloBean.myChangeEvent}"/> 
       </h:inputText>
       <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.name}" /></h2>  
</h:form>
```

an the managed bean

```
public void myChangeEvent( AjaxBehaviorEvent e ) {
    System.out.println( "VALUE CHANGED" );
}
```

The [`event` object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) will be given into our javascript part by the browser himself - So running this outside a on* - attribute won't work.

The javascript method `event.stopPropagation()` is an [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or seamingly also a javascript method (see [W3C school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)), preventing other events to be called bubbling down the DOM-tree.

Comment: +1 for the `stopPropagation()` - pressing `<Enter>` will submit the whole form by default, which the user probably doesn't want in this context.

Comment: +1 now I know the stop propatation in pure JSF which I was doing with `a4j:ajax` easily in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot apply your idea to my application this weekend because I am not at work but I just run a jsf-example from http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ and tested it with this modification. Chrome gives the following message: "httpError: The Http Transport returned a 0 status code. This is usually the result of mixing ajax and full requests. This is usually undesired, for both performance and data integrity reasons." As mabi told stopPropagation() submits the whole form and this should definitely be not the case. Can I just leave it out?

Comment: When I leave e.stopPropagation() out Chrome still tells me that I mix ajax and a full request

Comment: @Metalhead89: Added a description for "stop Propagation" to the answer - it's a method that prevents other actions to be executed. Part 2 "return false" prevents the form to be submitted. Don't let the stop Propagation out, it is kind of essential. :-)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your answer the first time. Now I re-inserted the stopPropagation but it still submits the whole form on pressing enter...so part 2 unfortunately does not help

Comment: That would be very surprising. Have you cleaned your browser-cache and are you very sure no error occured by copy/paste? Do a double-check and add an `alert('hi');` into the function just to see if it gets called correctly.

Comment: I found one mistake: it is called 'onkeypress' and not 'onkeypressed' but it still does not work right. I use FireBug for testing and wrote the following JavaScript code: 

onkeypress="(function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) {console.log('enter pressed');} else {console.log('somthing else pressed');}}(0));"

It always prints out the last statement, also when pressing enter. But I also know that 13 should be the right keyCode for the enter button. What am I mising?

Comment: When I print out the keyCode on FireBug (console.log(e.keyCode);) it tells me thet it is undefinied, which would explain why it jumps always in the else part

Comment: Thnx for the hint with `onkeypress`, that was the part I couldn't copy'n'paste ;-)

Comment: Okay, moved the instructions out of the `function(e)` - frame. Should work now. :-)